# Need Regex for First/last name, covering names from the entire World, india, china etc

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a simple regex validator for first, last names for my international site, could any recommend one to use?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to validate? What will be the rule?

Comment: Wait a minute, is it April 1st again?  Where are the unicorns?

Comment: There are approximately 176,255,831 sites on the internet with regular expression examples. Surely one of them has the example you need?

Comment: What have you tried? What are the rules exactly? Two or three alphabetic words?

Comment: Validating names is usually a **BAD** idea! You'll offend any user who isn't matched by your expression and you're setting yourself up for failure since you'll never be able to match every name worldwide.

Comment: @drwilcox Youre a little behind, I think it is up to 176,255,832 now.

Comment: ^Guys, cheer up. We all started somewhere and found an answer on a site like stackoverflow. Nobody was born knowing everything. It's a valid question, answer it or ignore it. Stackoverflow isn't about smart/complex/advanced questions and answers. It's just Q&A as long as the questions are valid. What's up with the Google it mentality around here lately?

Comment: Oops sorry guys! , Ok I won't test against validity, would you guys recommend testing against certain characters? I'd like to at least filter out some malicious characters, I'm using ASP.NET & the names will be stored in SQL server. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: @Baconbeastnz Yup, sanitize data. But don't validate names. These are two different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really validate names. Names can be anything so as long as you make sure there is a value in place, that's great. There's no law forbidding certain names or name syntax so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will match any valid name from anywhere in the world:

`Regex nameValidator = new Regex(".*");`

Unfortunately it will also match all invalid ones :(

If you want to discriminate between the two, you'll have to give us some rules. It's unlikely that any satisfactory rules exist, so I would recommend **NOT** validating names.